# Does lseek() trigger an actual mechanical disk seeking movement?

Tags: c, unix

Consider the following code:

```
lseek(fd, 100, 0); /* Seek to the 100th byte in the file fd. */
write(fd, buf, n); /* Write from that position. */
lseek(fd, 0, 0); /* Is this necessary? Will it trigger a actual disk movement? */
```

I'd like to `lseek` back to the beginning of the file, in case another line of code continues writing from that position thinking that it starts at the beginning of the file. First, is this good practice? Second...

I'd like to know if an `lseek` does trigger an actual disk movement. Or, is the disk movement triggered only in the event of an actual reading or writing.

Disk seeking is a huge performance hit, and I'd like to know the tradeoffs between such defensive coding practices and performance.

Comment: Why are you assuming the next read/write after this write will be at the start of the file?

Comment: You may also be interested in the [pwrite](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html) function, which combines a seek, write, and seek back to original position into a single operation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is a Windows or Unix type system, a regular file and you did nothing fancy with file open flags, none of those functions will trigger a disk seek.

It is likely that in 5 seconds or so, the buffer containing that new file data will be written to disk, along with everything else that happened.

Also, the file position that lseek sets is an entirely imaginary property of a file. It controls where data will read or write to in the file by default, but there are many functions that simply override file position.

As to if it is good practice I don't think it matters much. However, I've gotten out of the habit of using seek functions when writing to files because of multithreading. You might want to use pread and pwrite by preference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you elaborate on why the writing will happen approximately 5 seconds later instead of at the instance the code is run?

Comment: @kev: 5 seconds is the default in a Linux system using one of the EXT filesystems.

Comment: Thanks Zan, but I see the change immediately. Is there a place I can refer to to find out more about how this works?

Comment: @kev: You see the change immediately where? If you mean from the same system of course you do because all files are read and written from the file cache, not the actual hard disk.